# prove if is converges or diverges sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

find if it's converges or diverges, if converges find the limit:
$$\frac{(-1)^n n+1}{n^2+1}.$$

My proof: divided by n^2 so you have $\frac{(-1)^n(1/n+1/n^2)}{1+1/n^2}$
if I take the limit $n\to \infty $ I would get $(-1)^2 * 0$ so it would be $0$ then is converges

is that right? and limit is 0

Comment: you're much more likely to have answers if you format your math equations.

Comment: Are you asking if the sum of that expression converges or if that fraction itself converges...

Comment: the sequence is converges or diverges

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea. If you use absolute values and the squeeze theorem you can dodge the sign issues:

$$\left\vert\frac{(-1)^nn+1}{n^2+1}\right\vert\leq\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}=\frac{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\to\frac{0+0}{1+0}=0$$ as $$n\to\infty$$.